# Visual studio C# oracle database

Tags: c#, database, oracle, visual-studio-2013, connection-string

> I have a problem with only one possible solution. We have created a
>   school oracle database on the school's VPN. In my SQL Oracle Developer
>   I currently have this configuration:
>
> [image]
>
> I found different solutions for connecting to oracle from visual
>   studio, but I could not get any of them to run. All of the errors were
>   thrown by tns listener.  I don't know, if this is correct, but on the
>   view the connect type is Basic.
>
> All tutorials i found, was with using tns. Is tns the possible
>   problem?
>
> Sorry, for maybe bad question), but is it possible to configure Visual
>   studio for connecting to Oracle database with this configuration?

**I do not use connection string now, because i want just connect to database with Server Explorer. Here is view my available Data Sources and Providers.**

[image]

**And in my tnsnames.ora I have this:**

```
(test = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = fei-sql1.upceucebny.cz)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = ee11) ) )
```

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: I edited your question to hopefully be more understandable but I am still not entirely sure what you are asking, are you asking if TNS is the only way to configure an Oracle connection in VS-2013 ?

Comment: Please provide you Visual Studio connection string.

Comment: Yes. I proceeded as follows:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gw7OEqJ3gv8

And in my tnsnames.ora I have this:

`test =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = fei-sql1.upceucebny.cz)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ee11)
    )
  )`

Comment: SOLVED! replace SERVICE_NAME to SID and it works :-)) Thanks for all :-))